# How could I update git?

Tags: git, heroku

[image]I cannot find an easy way to upgrade git. Is there a way to upgrade from the command line in the terminal?

The git webpage recommends:

```
$ brew install git
```

`Brew` is a command not found...

I used the git-osx-installer on sourceforge, but after installing I don't see the software in my programs folder. Also `$ git --version` shows that I have still version `2.15.0`

Unfortunately, I don't remember how I managed to install git for the first time.

Comment: You probably didn’t install it. macOS comes with it preinstalled

Answer (score 2):

You can type `which git` to see where `git` happens to be installed on your computer. `brew` is not found because it is not a built-in to the system. You will have to install it first. For doing that, please see the instructions at [Homebrew's website](https://brew.sh/). Once you have `brew` installed, you can go on reinstalling `git`.

Comment: Thanks, installing homebrew looked good at the beginning but now it seems the installing process got stuck

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes I could resolve it, with brew install postgresql. This updated homebrew. And somehow I figured it out, how to upgrade git as well (trial and error with different posts on stackoverflow). But both, upgrading homebrew and git for mac seems really complicated to me. I cannot understand why this is not more user-friendly.